# resetting displayString to initial state when dismissing custom popover

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have implemented a custom popover in SwiftUI based on the approach in this [article](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2022/presenting-popovers-on-iphone-with-swiftui/).

So I created some custom view:

```
struct PopoverPicker<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var selection: Int
    let content: () -> Content
    let displayString: (Int) -> String

    @State private var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        content()
            .customPopover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                Picker("", selection: $selection) {
                    ForEach(Array(1...30), id: \.self) { value in
                        Text(displayString(value))
                            .tag(value)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                isPresented.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

Also some custom model for testing purpose

```
struct Model {
    var someInt: Int = 0
}
```

And finally I am using it in view like:

```
    @State private var someModel: Model = .init()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            PopoverPicker(
                selection: $someModel.someInt,
                content: {
                    Text("\(someModel.someInt)")
                },
                displayString: {
                    String($0)
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

Problem is when I use Picker to pick some new value, someInt is changed, but on dismissing custom popover, value in popover (from displayString) is returned to previous value (even new picked value is adapted in model).

This problem is not appearing in iOS 17.0.2 simulators, only in 16 and 15 ones.

I guess my mistake is in some view refreshing cycle, but I cannot find it

Was trying using .onChange to update displayString inside PopoverPicker, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Your code works when I change `.customPopover`to generic `.popover`.

Comment: Remove `displayString` related code completely, it is unneccesary, use `Text("\(value)"`. (Does not fix your issue but is just simpler)

Comment: Please post your code for customPopover, as this is where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With a `List`, you could try using an array of `Identifiable` IntModel,
and binding `$`. Tested on ios 16.4 simulator with `.popover`
instead of the `.customPopover`, since the code is not available.

```
 struct IntModel: Identifiable {
     let id = UUID()
     var someInt: Int
 }

 struct ContentView: View {
     @State var someModel: [IntModel] = [IntModel(someInt: 1), IntModel(someInt: 2), IntModel(someInt: 3), IntModel(someInt: 4)]

     var body: some View {
         List($someModel) { $item in
             PopoverPicker(
                 selection: $item.someInt,
                 content: {
                     Text("\(item.someInt)")
                 },
                 displayString: {
                     String($0)
                 }
             )
         }
     }
 }
```